# One Signal push notification getting failed if a custom category is used

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification, onesignal

In one of my one signal projects, I have created a custom category of notification channel from the one Signal dashboard itself, but sending notification with custom category getting failed for all the users and without custom category it works fine.

2 days ago, it was asking for the *server key* and *sender ID* for the configuration of Google Android (FCM) but now it asks for the *Service Account JSON* file for the configuration.